# library(RNeo4j) Error in library(RNeo4j) : there is no package named ‘RNeo4j’

Tags: r, neo4j, r-neo4j

When pasting library(RNeo4j) into the console I am getting the error above.
Running out of ideas. Please help, it might be very trivial

Comment: If you installed RNeo4j v1.4.1 (you can check with `packageVersion("RNeo4j")`), you'll likely encounter errors out of the box due to recent breaking changes in the httr package, which is one of RNeo4j's dependencies. I fixed this as of a few minutes ago. I'd go ahead and do `remove.packages("RNeo4j")` and then `devtools::install_github("nicolewhite/RNeo4j")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to install the package yet?

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("nicolewhite/RNeo4j")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just did this again. It seems that I was not patient enough to let the process finish when I tried for the first time. Let us consider this solvend then. Thanks again.